# Example on how to combine odata and extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, frontend, odata

Is there a blogpost or example on how to combine the ext-js grid with an odata datasource? I suspect it would require a custom datareader.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to extend Ext.data.DataReader abstract class for customised odata manipulations.

Comment: Have you seen examples of this? Or would i be the first to create it?

Comment: No, I haven't seen. I even don't know what's odata. Why don't have a try?

Comment: Also, you may take ArrayReader of JsonReader as an example. All you need is to modify only one method within it.

Comment: usually if examples don't exist, you might be the only one going this path, indicating better solutions exist probably ;) I'll give it a shot nonetheless. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You dont really need anything fancy, just set defaultHeaders in your DataProxy to : {'Accept':'application/json'}. Set the root property of the JsonStore to 'd' and you are good to go, no need of anything special i have it working that way and no problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127046-Query-Odata-Feed&p=582893&viewfull=1#post582893